# Ansible assert failure when source list holds more values than target list

Tags: ansible

I want to assert network configuration with our inventory using a single assert task.

```
    - name: Get running class-map config
      vars:
        ansible_connection: network_cli
      ios_command:
        commands:
          - 'sh run | in class-map match-any'
      register: show_policy

    - name: Render template to variable
      set_fact:
        tem_var: "{{ lookup( 'template', 'test_policy.j2' ).splitlines() }}"

    - name: Validate running class-map with acl
      ansible.builtin.assert:
        that:
          - "'{{item}}' in show_policy.stdout_lines[0]"
        success_msg: "TEST: {{ UNIT_HOSTNAME }}: VALIDATE RUNNING POLICY: PASSED"
        fail_msg: "TEST: {{ UNIT_HOSTNAME }}: VALIDATE RUNNING POLICY: FAILED"
      loop: "{{ tem_var }}"
```

Above assert works fine, but the configuration on the router sometimes holds more configuration than what is expected. I would like to use the same assert task as I am already using. So above assert should be used to also compare the 2 variables

"tem_var" is a variable generated from out inventory files.

Our inventory has for example 8 configuration lines, and the router has 9.

In that case I wan't the assert to fail, if the number of lines in each variable "show_policy" and "tem_var" is not the same.

I have done it succesfully with 2 additional tasks, but it would be nice if the assert module could fail instead.

This is working, but it adds up the number of tasks running:

```
    - name: Consistency check running
      set_fact: diff_list="{{ show_policy.stdout_lines[0] | difference(tem_var) }}"

    - name: CONSISTENCY CHECK FAILED !! Device has unvalidated config
      ansible.builtin.fail:
        msg: "CONSISTENCY FAILURE: Please remove {{ diff_list }} from {{ UNIT_HOSTNAME }}"
      when: diff_list|default("")|length > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

**How to assert failure when source list holds more values than target list?**

According your current question headline and current description

> *Our inventory has for example 8 configuration lines, and the router has 9.*
>
> *In that case I wan't the assert to fail, if the number of lines in each variable `show_policy` and `tem_var` is not the same.*

you would need just to compare the length of both lists.

The minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    show_policy:
      stdout_lines:
        - '1'
        - '2'

    tem_var:
      stdout_lines:
        - '1'
        - '2'
        - '3'

  tasks:

  - name: Assert failure
    ansible.builtin.assert:
      that: # the number of lines in each variable is the same
        - show_policy.stdout_lines | length == tem_var.stdout_lines | length
      success_msg: "VALIDATE RUNNING POLICY: PASSED"
      fail_msg: "VALIDATE RUNNING POLICY: FAILED"
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Assert failure] **********************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false
  assertion: show_policy.stdout_lines | length == tem_var.stdout_lines | length
  evaluated_to: false
  msg: 'VALIDATE RUNNING POLICY: FAILED'
  
TASK [Assert failure] **********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => changed=false
  msg: 'VALIDATE RUNNING POLICY: PASSED'
```

depending on the list length.

**Further Documentation**

- [`assert` module – Asserts given expressions are true](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/assert_module.html#examples)
- [Jinja2 Template Designer Documentation - List of Builtin Filters](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#builtin-filters)
- [`jinja-filters.length`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.length)

**Follow Ups**

If you are interested in the difference between the configuration (list), in example if settings are missing

- [Ansible: How to compare two list variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70897299/6771046)
- [How to compare lists in Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65341614/)

Comment: Thanks @U880D - but I am more looking after a solution where I can use this check in the assert task that I already have. Instead if having two asserts. If not possible, I will consider this solution.

Comment: "_I am more looking after a solution where I can use this check in the assert task that I already have._", then I recommend to edit your initial question and description, update your headline, provide much more details and description, explain what you are looking for and what you are not looking for and since there seems to be a strong discrepancy in what is written and what you expect.

Comment: I strongly disagree. You clearly understood what I am trying to accomplish. Except the fact that I wan't the same assert task to do it. I have now added that part to the question

Comment: Actually I do not understand that why I've requested more description. Do you try to compare the content of list elements or the amount of list elements (which are two totally different things)? Or do you try to do both, content of list elements and amount of list elements? How about the order of list elements then?

Comment: To rephrase the question in other words, are you looking for if there is a difference in between the lists or are your looking for what is the difference between the lists?

Comment: I actually solved it now. with the following in assert: "lookup('template', 'test_policy.j2').splitlines() in show_policy.stdout_lines" - So this request has changed allot now, so I think I have to close it and reopen a new question. This solution makes the assert fail even though the values in the list holds more or less. But it doesn't show which value is missing or shouldn't be there.

Comment: Thanks allot for your help and contribution with links and all